# Getting rotation angle from Eigen::Isometry2d

Tags: rotation, eigen, angle

I'm working with [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialGeometry.html) library and, in particular, 2d isometries to represent the pose of an object in a 2D world.

As you may know, this has three components: `x` and `y` for the position and an angle `theta` for the rotation.

Extracting the position components is straightforward:

```
Eigen::Isometry2d t;
double x = t.translation().x();
double y = t.translation().y();
```

For the rotation, one can use a formula like:

```
double theta = atan2(t(1, 0), t(0, 0));
```

This is tested and works fine, but it's a bit inconvenient to write it all the times. Therefore my question is if someone knows a nicer way to get `theta` by just calling Eigen methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a `Rotation2Dd` object from the linear part of the transformation (and if you prefer having a scalar, extract the angle using `.angle()`):

```
double theta = Eigen::Rotation2Dd(t.linear()).angle();
```